# How can i update data in Cosmos Azure (NOSQL) , using Azure function with HTTP trigger POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm a newbie Azure, and i'm trying to use Azure function for HTTP trigger NodeJS,
I already have an NoSQL database on Azure Cosmos.
Example:

```html
{
   ...
   "shop":{
      "fruits":[
         "orange",
         "strawberry",
         "lemon"
      ],
      "clothes":[
         "man",
         "woman",
         "babies"
      ]
   }
   ...
}
```

Then i want to ADD a new fruit named **apple** into **fruits** array, or REMOVE **babies** out of **clothes**. Also UPDATE **man** to **men**,
How can i do ?
I found the **context.bindings**. But i haven't known how to use it yet,
Does anyone can help me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample function which increments `num` field of the document.

`function.json`

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "HttpTriggerJSUpdateDocument/{docid}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "MyDB",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "id": "{docid}",
      "connection": "mydocdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "MyDB",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "createIfNotExists": false,
      "connection": "mydocdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

`index.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    let inputDocument = context.bindings.inputDocument;
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger, current value: ' + 
        (inputDocument && inputDocument.num));

    inputDocument.num = inputDocument.num + 1;

    context.bindings.outputDocument = inputDocument;

    context.res = {
        body: 'Result is ' + inputDocument.num
    };
    context.done();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! @Mikkail

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Net;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, out object taskDocument, TraceWriter log)
{
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    string task = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "task", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    string duedate = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "duedate", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    taskDocument = new {
        name = name,
        duedate = duedate.ToString(),
        task = task
    };

    if (name != "" && task != "") {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

and function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "taskDocument",
      "databaseName": "taskDatabase",
      "collectionName": "TaskCollection",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connection": "DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Use coresponding name instead for task.